# Doxygen error: Found ';' while parsing initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, doxygen

Doxygen 1.8.11 is choking on the following definition, which I simplified as much as I could without losing the warning message:

```
template <class T>
struct MySpecialization<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo(
                             std::declval<double>()))>> : std::true_type {};
```

The warning is:

```
warning: Found ';' while parsing initializer list! (doxygen could be confused by a macro call without semicolon)
```

Interestingly, Doxygen is fine with the following:

```
template <class T>
struct MySpecialization<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo())>> : std::true_type {};
```

which is basically the same definition without an argument to `foo`.

I would very much appreciate a workaround. In the worst case, I would like to somehow cause Doxygen to ignore this definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just committed a fix in GitHub for this issue, see https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/985faf287233badf65fa33d21bde17afa6970d60

Comment: Thanks! Can I assume that version 1.8.13. will have this fix integrated?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes indeed.

Comment: I would very much appreciate if you could look at the questions I posted today about some behaviors of Doxygen that look like definite bugs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386042/include-guards-and-commented-out-doxygen-comments-affect-the-output-of-doxygen, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382849/doxygen-does-not-see-the-description-of-a-pre-processor-symbol, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358150/doxygen-demands-that-an-include-guard-be-documented

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the [docs](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#faq_code). Use doxygen's `\cond` and `\endcond` commands or use preprocessor defines.

```
/// \cond NOPE
template <class T>
struct MySpecialization<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo(
                             std::declval<double>()))>> : std::true_type {};
/// \endcond
```

With preprocessor defines you can add Doxygen-friendly definition. For example, the Qt project does this.

```
#ifdef DOXYGEN_WORKING
template <class T>
struct MySpecialization<T, something_that_doxygen_understands> : std::true_type {};
#else
template <class T>
struct MySpecialization<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo(
                             std::declval<double>()))>> : std::true_type {};
#endif
```

and add `PREDEFINED = DOXYGEN_WORKING` to your config file.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: That is the alternative. The example given makes use of `\cond` and `\endcode`. Visit the documentation; it's in the _frequently asked questions_ list, which should have been your very first port of call.... This answer author even linked you directly to the specific page for maximum convenience.

Comment: But what exactly in the example definition confuses Doxygen?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning C++ is non-trivial to parse, and the tool predates clang-as-a-library. You'd probably have to delve deep into the code to find what exactly is the problem, but I don't know how that would be more helpful than doing what everyone else does ;)

Comment: Thank you. With this in mind, I also accept the criticism for not looking up the documentation first.