# Include-guards and commented out Doxygen comments affect the output of Doxygen

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, doxygen

The behavior of Doxygen 1.8.11 for the following example is really bizarre:

File `test.h`:

```
/// \file

/// \namespace N1
/// Namespace N1.
namespace N1 {

#include "a.h"

} // namespace

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

File `a.h`:

```
/// \file

/// \namespace N1::N2
/// Namespace N2
namespace N2 {

#include "b.h"

} // namespace
```

File `b.h`:

```
/// \file

// class A does not appear without the commented Doxygen comments below!
// /// \cond None
#ifndef GUARD
#define GUARD
// /// \endcond

/// Class A
class A {};

// /// \cond None
#endif
// /// \endcond
```

The class `A` appears in the documentation of `N1::N2` only if the include-guard in `b.h` is not present or is conditioned out. Interestingly, even having the conditioning comments commented out as in the example suffices to have the class `A` appear!

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: @m8mble Don't you find the described phenomenon strange and requiring an explanation?

Comment: So, your question is about my opinion? Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @m8mble No, my question is about your explanation of the described phenomenon.

Comment: It's probably some form of doxygen bug, but since you've already discovered a workaround there is not much to explain. Doxygen neither is a preprocessor nor a compiler - it will never fully understand C++.